# Merging two queries to one. both have group by on the same field

Tags: sql

I have the following tables

```
table A
{SID, IP)

table B
(SID, PID)

table C
(SID, PID)
```

I have the following two querys.

```
select IP, count (IP) as hits from A group by IP  

IP      hits
1       100
2       400
3       250

select IP, count(IP) as clicks from table A join table b on A.SID = B.SID 

IP      clicks
1       10
2       40
3       25


select IP, count(IP) as bought from A join B on A.SID = B.SID join C on C.SID = B.SID

IP      bought
1       1
2       4
3       2
```

how can I write a query that genartes the following result in one shot.

```
IP      hits    clicks  Bought
1       100     10      1
2       400     40      4
3       250     25      2
```

Comment: Can you just use `count(distinct SID)` and a simple three-table query? Sample data would help give a better answer.

Comment: here is the sample data. basically SID is 1-N between table A and table B and same as Table A and table C. PID is not important here. Sample data

A (SID, IP)
{
1, 1
2, 1
3, 2 
4, 2 
5, 2 
6, 2 
7, 3 
8, 3
9, 3
10, 3
11, 3
12, 3
13, 3
}

B (SID, PID)
{
1, 1
1, 2 
1, 3 
1, 4 
1, 5 
2, 1 
2, 12
2, 15
2, 16
2, 17
2, 18
}

C (SID, PID)
{
1, 1
2, 1 
2, 12
2, 15
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join em all together:

```
SELECT a.IP, a.hits, b.clicks, c.bought
FROM (select IP, count (IP) as hits from A group by IP) a
JOIN (select IP, count(IP) as clicks from table A join table b on A.SID = B.SID group by IP) b on a.ip = b.ip
JOIN (select IP, count(IP) as bought from A join B on A.SID = B.SID join C on C.SID = B.SID group by IP) c ON a.ip = c.ip
```

Note you might want to use LEFT joins if some of your tables don't have some of the IP values.

This is basic SQL -- check out any introductory text for more information.

Comment: SIP is 1:N between table A and others.

Comment: @Paymon - just try it -- each of the sub-queries has a group by IP (or should)

Answer (score 0):

try left joins:

```
select a.*, b.* from (
select IP, count (IP) as hits from A group by IP)a left join (
select IP, count(IP) as clicks from table A join table b on A.SID = B.SID)b on a.ip = b.ip
```

.. and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this may be equivalent although the join might product a lot of rows. This is a stab in the dark since I don't know how `SID` relates in these tables.

```
select
    A.IP,
    count(distinct A.SID) as hits,
    count(distinct B.SID) as clicks,
    count(distinct C.SID) as bought
from
    A
    inner join B
        on A.SID = B.SID
    inner join C
        on C.SID = B.SID
group by
    A.IP
```